# Program not reading from .txt file

Tags: java

I am trying to read three variables from a txt file called input
input.txt contains 12 33.44 and Peter 
when I  run the program these variables are not outputted

```
package lab9;
import java.util.Scanner;              // Needed to use Scanner for input
import java.io.File;                   // Needed to use File
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  // Needed for file operation

public class FileScanner 
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) 
  // Needed for file operation 
         throws FileNotFoundException 
   {  

// Declare the int variable
       int a=0;
 //Declare the floating point number
       double b=0;
 //Declare the string variable
       String s=null;
 //Declare a variable to hold the sum
       double sum =0;
// Create a file object that takes "input.txt" as input
       File oInput= new File("input.txt") ;
// Setup a Scanner to read from the text file that you created
       Scanner gilz=new Scanner(oInput);

// use nextInt() to read the integer
       while (gilz.hasNextInt())
       {
         a = gilz.nextInt();
       }
         System.out.println ("the integer read is " + a);

// use nextDouble() to read double
     while(gilz.hasNextDouble())
     {
         b = gilz.nextDouble();
     }
         System.out.println ("the floating point number read is "+ b);

// use next() to read String
       while(gilz.hasNextLine())
       {
       s = gilz.nextLine();
       }
         System.out.println ("the string read is "+ s);
       while((gilz.hasNextDouble())&&(gilz.hasNextInt()))
       {
           sum = a + b;
       }
           System.out.println("HI! "+s +", the sum of "+a+"and "+b+" is "+sum);
    }
}
```

when I try to run the program I get no output , no variables are printed on the screen 
how do I get my scanner to read from the txt file using .nextInt() or .next() methods ?

Comment: Are any errors being output? Could you catch the ``FileNotFound`` exception and print a stack trace?

Comment: Just tried the code and it does output the variables. Except the sum is always 0 as there are no more numbers in the file

Answer (score -2):

Use the complete path of the file that you'll read.
I am using an example using FileReader and BufferedReader, you'll need to do the same using new `File("c:\\input.txt)`.

Look at the example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\input.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think that `BufferedReader(FileReader))` is better here than `Scanner(File)`? What problems does it solve?

Comment: You can see here the answer: http://en.allexperts.com/q/Java-1046/2009/2/Difference-Scanner-Method-Buffered.htm

Comment: I didn't ask what are differences between these two approaches. I asked why you think `BufferedReader(FileReader)` should be used here instead of `Scanner(File)`? How does it solve OP problem?

Comment: Once scanner will have more methods of reading, bufferedreader is faster than scanner... just because of this, and, of course, is "thread safe".

Comment: OK, but how does it solve OP problem? Notice that ["works for me"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid) is not valid answer but comment saying that question needs more details about real problem.

Comment: Just i've changed the answer about the path... Well, who will read these comments will learn a lot about bufferedreader now heh? "Diogo, you could focus on the path, not about objects he is using..." Just a tip. Thanks for the observation.